# Android app is not opening in Android 10 version, released on 3 Sept 2019

Tags: java, android, android-launcher, launching-application, android-10.0

I tried to install my app on new version of android released on 03 Sept 2019.
Its android 10 with API level 29.

min version : 16,
targeted version 29 tried with 26 too.

Log is,

```
 Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
 Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
 Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
 The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
 The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
 I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
 I/MultiDex: Installing application
 I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
 I/MultiDex: Installing application
 I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.

 A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x1c in tid 19282 (com.tab.and2), pid 19282 (com.tab.and2)
```

Dependencies,

[image]

Manifest application tag

```
<application
        android:name="com.abc.app.MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:allowClearUserData="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
```

Application class

```
public class MyApp extends MultiDexApplication {
```

Please help me if you have any solution regarding same.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show your dependency

Comment: enable MultiDex support for the project

Comment: Check my dependency now, Already enabled MultiDex.

Comment: Please post your manifest file and your application class (if your project uses an own application class)

Comment: Check now, Manifest and app file.